# error in getting data of first postion in a listview in android application

Tags: android

I am developing an android application.I have a listview in which i have 5 items.On each item click dere are 5 different views.On i the first item click i have made a registeration form.I want that when i click on second item that registeration form should be displayed ie data on the first item should be displayed.Is it possible,??.If yes can anyone guide me...how to implement this ..

below is my listview java class code
http://pastebin.com/tXDGdfb2

below is my provider activity java class code
http://pastebin.com/JdewveUp

Regards
Tushar Sahni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is check whether first one was clicked or not
If first item is clicked then on the click of second application, Create a view
which has both the fist and second Item view as sub views.

I hope that should work

Thanks

Himanshu

Comment: ,,actually i have a add button on the first view.i want that when i click on add data gets added automatically in first view.tHE DATA is comg from url.I have done parsing